# There is an issue with the MaterialDatePicker text color when manually entering the date in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-styles, android-datepicker

I am facing the issue unable to change the white color in manually enter the date in my dialog. How would I change this color ?
[image]

I tried this and still not working.

```
<style name="MaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">

        <!-- Header panel -->
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderLayout">@style/MaterialCalendar.HeaderLayout1</item>
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/TextButton.Dialog1</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/TextButton.Dialog1</item>

    </style>
```

```
<style name="MaterialCalendar.HeaderLayout1" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderLayout">
        <!--<item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>-->
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:headerMonthTextAppearance">@color/black</item>

    </style>
    <style name="TextButton.Dialog1" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
     </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use **Android Studio** , go to Layout and click an you're layout and open  Design  and looking for textColor and there you have sumach change , or click Code , and write in EditText Datum `android:textColor="#000000"`
. try this and tell me the result  .
tyr

Comment: your code is  for layout but I want to change color in material date dialogue

Comment: <item name="android:editTextColor">

Comment: show please the code

Comment: <style name="MaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
         <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/black</item>
  </style>


 like this and then used this 
  R.style.MaterialCalendarTheme
 into your MaterialDatePicker instance